# How to user KafkaAdminClient to set Quota limits？

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I find alterConfigs in KafkaAdminClient,So I want to set Quota limits via KafkaAdminClient, Can it even possible? and How to set the config Map?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, quota-related broker configs can only be updated using Zookeeper(namely by ConfigCommand). Users cannot set these values by AdminClient. [KIP-248](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-248+-+Create+New+ConfigCommand+That+Uses+The+New+AdminClient#KIP-248-CreateNewConfigCommandThatUsesTheNewAdminClient-AlterQuotas) will migrate all of the functions to the new AdminClient. See it for more details.